merging lists with identical elements but in different order in pandas series into one unique lists
Consider this simple dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'category' :[['Restaurants', 'Pizza'],  ['Pizza', 'Restaurants'],  ['Restaurants', 'Mexican']]})

df:

The issue is that the category in the first two rows are essentially identical, just in different order. My goal is to collapse the two into one (does not matter which one). So, the resulting df should look like:

or:

I thought about getting the indices of the rows with essentially the same categories (rows indexed 0 and 1 in this example) and then find a way to replace all with one. But I am not sure if my code is correct and also the whole dataset is huge so this is inefficient:
identical_idx = []
df_length = len(df)
for i in range(df_length):
    for j in range(df_length):
        if i!=j:
            if set(df.category.iloc[i]) == set(df.category.iloc[j]): identical_idx.append([i, j])

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

As easy option would be to sort the lists:
df['category'] = df['category'].map(sorted)

Output:
                 category
0    [Pizza, Restaurants]
1    [Pizza, Restaurants]
2  [Mexican, Restaurants]

I would probably convert them to set/frozenset, which will be more efficient for grouping operations:
df['category'] = df['category'].map(frozenset)

Output:
                 category
0    (Pizza, Restaurants)
1    (Pizza, Restaurants)
2  (Mexican, Restaurants)


Geniusly simple

One follow-up question: imagine there was a second column called industry and for each industry, there are different categories. So, for example, those 3 rows in this example data would have the value restaurant in the industry column. In that case, should the sorting be done by industry? Something like df.groupby('industry')['category'].map(sorted) or this is done row by row regardless of any grouping of rows?

Asking because when I follow your method and then do something like df..groupby('industry')['category'].value_counts(), I get unexpected results and am trying to figure out where the issue is

Can you give a reproducible exemple and the expected output? I don't really understand what you want.
